# How to group events into session based on their t

Tags: mysql, session, group-by, druid

I have a table containing a list of events carried out by users and the time of the event.

There are 2 possible events that a user can perform, `A` and `B`.

> I would like to group the events into sessions, and count how many times each event took place per session.

My main difficulty is that I would like to have `sessions end after 30min of inactivity`, and the next activity would be considered as a new session.

[image]

Given the data above, I would like the result to be as indicated below.

[image]

P.S The timestamp is stored in milliseconds. I wrote it down this way in order to make my question more readable.

Comment: Please, prepare a live demo, for example here: http://sqlfiddle.com/

Comment: It would have been very simple if MySQL had a `LAG` function.